# Select blocking on available write fdset until the process is interrupted and renewed

Tags: c++, sockets, select, tcp, server

I have a TCP server app and a TCP client app. The server runs in multiple threads where in one thread a select() call is blocking with an indefinite timeout:

```cpp
while(running) {
    initFdSets();
    nfds = select(max_fd + 1, &listened_fdset, &write_fdset, &exception_fdset, NULL);
    ...
    reads_from_fds_in_listened_fdset();
    writes_to_fds_in_write_fdset();
}
```

meanwhile, in the other thread a valid socket file descriptor is added for the first time to the write fd set:

```cpp
FD_SET(connection_socket_fd, write_fdset_ptr);
```

and the select() call still blocks.
During that time, the client app is blocking on a read() call that wants to read from the other side of the connection between the two:

```cpp
read(sockfd, &msgType, sizeof(int32_t));
```

and nothing happens untill I interrupt the server app in debug mode and then resume it. After doing so, select() returns, a proper stream of bytes is sent to the client app and recieved as planned. Writefdset is reinitialized before the select() call... but the server behavior doesn't change in the new while() iteration.

Yes, all the sets are cleared using FD_ZERO and re-initialized before select() is called (including the file descriptor from the 2nd snippet).

I'll be thankful for a resoution to this problem as it is the last one that I have to get rid of from my project - but have no idea how and why it happens.

Comment: "_meanwhile, in the other thread a valid socket file descriptor is added for the first time to the write fd set_" - You shouldn't change the set from one thread while using it in another at the same time. You need all your file descriptors in the set before you call `select`.

Comment: I tought it's legal and doing so would make writes in my server app purely event-driven. At least, this is what my teacher had requested of me...

Comment: @SpriteYagami "*I tought it's legal*" - you thought wrong "*this is what my teacher had requested of me*" - then either your teacher is wrong, or you have misunderstood what you were told

Comment: That too may be the case, though he did stress the part about the writes being event-driven. Anyway, I'll ask him about it once more and as of now, thank you for pointing out the illegal calls.

Comment: You can still make it event driven without using select timeouts (which introduces polling) without changing the FD_SET from a second thread while the FD_SET is in use. You can introduce a wake-up file descriptor in the FD_SET that you use to signal `select` to wake up (this is called [the self-pipe trick](https://www.google.com/search?q=select+%22self-pipe+trick%22)) - or simpler, if you add file descriptors, it's usually a direct result of some other event that you already `select` on. Then add the new descriptor in the same thread as you do `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the man page for select here: [Select Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

The reason select is hanging is because you need to pass it a timeval as an argument in order to tell it it should be timing out. To quote:

```
   The timeout
       The time structures involved are defined in <sys/time.h> and look
       like

           struct timeval {
               long    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
               long    tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
           };

       and

           struct timespec {
               long    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
               long    tv_nsec;        /* nanoseconds */
           };

       (However, see below on the POSIX.1 versions.)

       Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a
       non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond
       precision.

       On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not
       slept; most other implementations do not do this.  (POSIX.1 permits
       either behavior.)  This causes problems both when Linux code which
       reads timeout is ported to other operating systems, and when code is
       ported to Linux that reuses a struct timeval for multiple select()s
       in a loop without reinitializing it.  Consider timeout to be unde‐
       fined after select() returns.
```

Thus this should fix your problem:

```
while(running) {
    timeval tv = {};
    static constexpr long myTimeoutInMicros = 10000; // Put your desired timeout here.
    tv.tv_usec = myTimeoutInMicros;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    initFdSets();
    nfds = select(max_fd + 1, &listened_fdset, &write_fdset, &exception_fdset, &tv);
    ...
    reads_from_fds_in_listened_fdset();
    writes_to_fds_in_write_fdset();
}
```

I also suggest doing additional reading with beej's networking guide: [Beejs Networking Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) which is a comprehensive source for bsd style socket call networking.

Edit: It's worth noting that on Solaris 10/Solaris 11 (not sure about IlumOs) select will timeout regardless of whether or not a timeval is provided.

Comment: The thing is, I want the call to select() to return if and only if I can write, read or an exception occures. I don't want it to time out at any point.

Comment: Concurrent read/writes are undefined behavior (modifying fdsets from off the reading thread without mutex / atomic mechanisms). My guess is that select doesn't expect your fdset to change while it's blocking. My assumption is that if you let it time out and used the calls returns to know whether or not there's something is ready for read/write it would timeout, see there's nothing, go back to the top of the loop and use the newly set values and work as you intend. I'd still fix the concurrency issue though.

Comment: *Changing the FD sets while `select()` is running* is what's undefined. No amount of mutex/semaphores will change that. `select()` copies the FD sets into the kernel and then executes in the kernel. You can do whatever you like to the FD sets but an already executing `select()` won't see it.